Use shortcut in Safari search bar to visit website
Is there a Safari-native way to use a kind of "shortcut" in the search bar to go directly to a website?
For instance, to go directly to the Python Pandas GitHub issues page, I would like define a shortcut that allows me to just type ghpd (or similar) in the search bar, press return and be directed there.
I know that the xSearch for Safari extension offers this ability, if the `Enable Empty Searches" option is configured... but I would prefer not to use a third-party extension for this.

Note this functionality is slightly different from the "search shortcuts" that Safari natively supports - and is offered by these extensions:

QueryDial
xSearch
Keyword Search


You can use the macOS native text replacements to do this.
System Settings > Keyboard > Text Input > Text Replacements ...
Now when I type ghpd it is replaced with https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues
Note that this will expand in any text field, so it you only want the expansion to happen in Safari this may not work for you.
And there are a number of third party text replacement tools which provide additional functionality than the native macOS feature does, including limiting to specific applications.

